How to visualize my Facebook chat history?
The "first level" problem I am trying to solve is to find out what I did at a certain date and with who I did it.
The second level problem: sometimes I look at my Google Timeline (location history) and have no clue why I went to a certain place and with who. Same thing can happen when I look at my credit card bill, call history in my phone etc.
One good way (I think it would help in at least 75 % of the cases) to find the answer to these questions would be to look in my Facebook chat history and see who I chatted with around that day and what we were talking about, but there is no built in way in Facebook Messenger to find all messages between two dates.
I have downloaded my complete Facebook Messenger chat history in JSON and am considering how to present it in a way that is useful for the purpose described above.
I am thinking that I could program something in Python or Java that creates a timeline with all messages "attached" but there are 275 000 messages from 5500 recipients sent over 15 yeats so the displaying of it requires something extraordinary.
How do I display these messages in a useful and user friendly way?
I think I have some requirements:

The recipients must be possible to switch on and off. C.f. how layers work in photo editing software. So basically one layer per recipient.

You need zoom or zoom like behaviour. The messages will be displayed per second. 15 years ≈ 473 000 000 seconds. You will need a canvas with that many pixels in one direction.

(1) goes in "both directions" - for usability purposes I need to be able to turn on all "layers" (that is, recipients) I communicated with between two dates. For performance reasons you don't want to turn on all 5500 layers just to see the 10 recipients you communicated with during a certain period, so it must be possible to search both by recipient as well as by period.


1 and 2 doesn't literally need to be visualized "graphically", something like a spreadsheet could maybe do it, but then you need a spreadsheet with 473 million lines. Or maybe not. Depending on how you define stuff.
I know this question is quite "open ended" and you usually don't like that, but that is why I started it with explaining the underlying problem. I am looking for a way to recreate what I did a certain day and with who, and sorting and displaying my Facebook Messenger history would be a good start (later on I might add my SMS history, call log, e-mail archive etc to this timeline). I have the data (FB chat history) but I don't know how to organize it in a useful way for my purpose. That is the basic question.
I could imagine PDFs or SVGs could support this setup, but e.g., can they handle 5500 layers? And a document that is half a billion of pixels in at least one direction? Probably not? Should I instead use a spreadsheet? Or even a SQL-table?
